# Basics of Location recording

Tags: location-recording

I will be recording my first film shoot this month. To this point, all of my work has been Audio-post. I was just wondering how people keep records of what they are recording? I know about sound reports, but am finding it difficult to find out how they really work?

How do I really keep track of what I'm recording?

Any advise anybody can offer would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can find printable production sound report templates [here](http://www.gothamsound.com/main.shtml?page=docs).

A great read on production sound essentials [here](http://www.amps.net/technical/Essentials.htm).

Comment: That's very kind of you Soundie! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few tips from my experience:

You'll want to speak to the script supervisor (scripty) and ask them to keep you updated as to what scene/take you're on.  On your sound report you'll want to write down the scene and take numbers and keep track of how many mics/channels you used and make notes regarding the quality of the recording (was the an airplane going by during the take?  was the speech intelligible? etc.)  If there are problems make sure you let the director know that sound had a problem and ask for another take.  If you don't get another take, write that on your report ("no reshoot as per director").

Some recorders will allow you to enter a name for your recording - if so, enter the scene: "01A_T" as in Scene 01 Alpha, Take_  The recorder should add a number each time you do another take so you shouldn't have to manually enter the number each time you do a take.  If your recorder doesn't allow you to name your tracks, you should probably write on your sound reports the name your recorder has assigned to the recording.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. Shoot went well thanks to your help guys.